# How to access google drive from compute engine

Tags: google-compute-engine

I haven't used GCE before but was planning on using it for some CPU bound R scripts.

I see that on the network section of pricing it says there is free egress and ingress with google drive.  I don't see any documentation on how to access my google drive from within a GCE.  Is there documentation on this that someone can point me towards?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I recommend using Google Cloud Storage instead of drive. Drive is a more consumer oriented (and expensive) product. Its extra features are geared towards file management and not moving around data blobs which is what you would need when programming.

If you really want to use it you can drive, you can find the API documentation at https://developers.google.com/drive/

Drive is NOT part of the Google Cloud Platform and there are no special instructions or integrations other than the network pricing.

Comment: "there are no special instructions or integrations" that's what I needed.  Since, as you mention, there is special network pricing for drive I assumed there was a special way to access it.

Comment: So I should just access it the same way I would from home right?

Comment: Does anyone know if the 2TB I pay for with Google Drive is available through GCE?  Or will I also be charged for, like, 100GB through that system?

Comment: Pricing is completely separate. GCS charges by number of bytes saved in GCS and Drive charges depending on the maximum you are allowed to save in Drive. Free Drive space cannot be used for GCS.

Answer (score 1):

As far an I can tell, there is no out of the box way to do it from a compute engine except using 3rd party tool like `gdrive`, it can be used in Linux, Windows CEs.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, there's no official solution. However, there is an open-source project, [google-drive-ocamlfuse](https://github.com/astrada/google-drive-ocamlfuse), which allows you to mount Google Drive onto your VM without much effort. Perform the installation as described on the main page, and then [follow these steps for headless usage and authorization.](https://github.com/astrada/google-drive-ocamlfuse/wiki/Headless-Usage-&-Authorization)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above, My Drive can be accessed in a GCP Linux compute instance via several other tools:
https://itsfoss.com/use-google-drive-linux/

The details of how the access is performed varies, but the end result is that My Drive will essentially appear in your Linux file system.

Be careful, however, because these programs may have bugs that can delete everything in My Drive (I had this happen with InSync -- I did the trial run then uninstalled and deleted the InSync folder, then later re-installed.  After re-install InSync saw that the folder was deleted, so it thought I wanted to delete everything in My Drive -- that was a very bad day.)