# Is it possible to run perl in google drive

Tags: perl, google-drive-api

I have uploaded my entire perl directory to google drive, including perl.exe, /lib,   perl scripts, and data files.

Is it possible to run perl.exe on perl scripts using the data files, within the google drive?

If so, where can I find out how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google drive is a File storge system.

It is not a server that can run any applications.

Comment: ...but it is possible to run on a [Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/) machine. There's even a [free tier](https://cloud.google.com/free). (You have a to give a credit card after a month, but it's still free.)

Comment: There is a big difference between Google drive and Google cloud

Comment: Yes. My comment is a continuation of your answer, not a replacement.

Comment: Haven't tried but according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31014354/how-to-access-google-drive-from-compute-engine it should be possible to access your google drive from your google clound machine (or local linux perhaps). I'm guessing it will be slow.